# Getting number from a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am scraping some website content which is like this - **"Company Stock Rs. 7100"**.

Now, what i want is to extract the numeric value from this string. I tried split but something or the other goes wrong with my regular expression.

Please let me know how to get this value.

Comment: is the number always going to be on the end of the string?

Comment: Will the numbers always be at the end? Will the text always be "Company Stock".. ?

Comment: Yes the numbers are always going to be at the end

Comment: @RobLevine. What difference does it make? He doesn't want **only** the numbers that in the end.

Comment: "but something or the other goes wrong with my regular expression." After asking 117 questions and with a rep of almost 2500, you would think that you would know by now: Post some code to show us what you've tried.

Comment: @adelphus, i am really bad at regex. Always think of reading this but dunno why i skip the regex chapter in every language. Apologies as its a very basic question.

Comment: @gdoron the OP said "what i want is to extract the numeric value from this string". If the numbers are always at the end, this lets us construct a more specific regex that to cater for that expectation. If the numbers can be anywhere, I'd construct a less specific one, but this has risks associated with it - such as if another number appears in the text sometimes. Same reasoning for asking about the text itself. When scraping external data, it pays to be as specific as you can to make sure you've scraped sane data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use:

```
var result = Regex.Match(input, @"\d+").Value;
```

If you want to find only number which is last "entity" in the string you should use this regex:

```
\d+$
```

If you want to match last number in the string, you can use:

```
\d+(?!\D*\d)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int val = int.Parse(Regex.Match(input, @"\d+", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value);
```

Answer (score 5):

I always liked `LINQ`:

```
var theNumber = theString.Where(x => char.IsNumber(x));
```

Though `Regex` sounds like the native choice...

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk. You're right, I just removed it... =) thanks

Comment: What about string like: `1 a 2`?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk. You will get `12`. I wrote `Regex` is the native choice. I just showed another way with `LINQ`. (I would use `Regex`, if that's your point...)

Comment: But this returns IEnumerable<char>() but not a string, isn't it?

Comment: @Flowerking. I think you can write `new string(theString)` to get it as a string.

Comment: Can be written `theString.Where(char.IsNumber);`

Answer (score 1):

This code will return the integer at the end of the string. This will work better than the regular expressions in the case that there is a number somewhere else in the string.

```
    public int getLastInt(string line)
    {
        int offset = line.Length;
        for (int i = line.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            char c = line[i];
            if (char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                offset--;
            }
            else
            {
                if (offset == line.Length)
                {
                    // No int at the end
                    return -1;
                }
                return int.Parse(line.Substring(offset));
            }
        }
        return int.Parse(line.Substring(offset));
    }
```

Comment: "This will work better than the regular expressions in the case that there is a number somewhere else in the string." - in what sense? One can easily make a regex to only match numbers at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

If your number is always after the last space and your string always ends with this number, you can get it this way:

```
str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer ....it is separating numeric from string using C#....

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String details = "XSD34AB67";
        string numeric = "";
        string nonnumeric = "";
        char[] mychar = details.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char ch in mychar)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(ch))
            {

                numeric = numeric + ch.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                nonnumeric = nonnumeric + ch.ToString();
            }
        }

        int i = Convert.ToInt32(numeric);
        Console.WriteLine(numeric);
        Console.WriteLine(nonnumeric);
        Console.ReadLine();



    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\d+` to match the first occurrence of a number:

```
string num = Regex.Match(input, @"\d+").Value;
```